# Ionic 2 iterate element in an array

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to iterate each element of an array after  a certain interval of time like 2sec then display it. When i try doing so it console logs successfully but when i try pushing it into `msg`  so achieve my aim i get an `ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'msg' of undefined at timer` Is there something am missing or a better solution ?

```
export class AuthPage {

    public verifyPhone : string;
    public collection = 'clients';
    public data;
    public user;
    public response;
    count : number;
    msg : any[];

    constructor(public navCtrl : NavController, public navParams : NavParams, public afs : AngularFirestore, public appService : AppServiceProvider, private alertCtrl : AlertController,) {


        let messages=[
            'Welcome to Fight Rabbit',
            'We are going to ask you a few questions to help setup your account',
            'What\'s your Phone Number?'
        ]
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            timer()

        }, 2000)

        var count = 0;
        function timer() {
            this.msg=[];
            if (count < messages.length) {
                this.msg.push(messages[count])
                console.log(messages[count],count)
                count += 1
            } else {
                clearInterval(interval)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix would be:

```
export class AuthPage {

    public verifyPhone : string;
    public collection = 'clients';
    public data;
    public user;
    public response;
    count : number;
    msg : any[];

    constructor(public navCtrl : NavController, public navParams : NavParams, public afs : AngularFirestore, public appService : AppServiceProvider, private alertCtrl : AlertController,) {


        let messages=[
            'Welcome to Fight Rabbit',
            'We are going to ask you a few questions to help setup your account',
            'What\'s your Phone Number?'
        ]

        var count = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.msg=[];
            if (count < messages.length) {
                this.msg.push(messages[count])
                console.log(messages[count],count)
                count += 1
            } else {
                clearInterval(interval)
            }    
        }, 2000)
    }
}
```

Comment: but the array is being cleared after the second iterations

Comment: @GeraldBrigen That's another question you could post :)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the issue with the scope.

Try to replace your code with this one :

```
    export class AuthPage {
    msg : any[];
    count = 0;
    .......

    constructor(public navCtrl : NavController, public navParams : NavParams, public afs : AngularFirestore, public appService : AppServiceProvider, private alertCtrl : AlertController,) {
        const messages = [
            'Welcome to Fight Rabbit',
            'We are going to ask you a few questions to help setup your account',
            'What\'s your Phone Number?'
        ]
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.timer()
        }, 2000)

        this.count = 0;
    }

    timer() {
      this.msg = [];
      if (count < messages.length) {
          this.msg.push(messages[count])
          console.log(messages[count],count)
          count += 1
      } else {
          clearInterval(interval)
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the issue exactly was it isn’t pushing items ‘msg’ array

Comment: what's the error now in console? can you reproduce your error on https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-28wfs1 ?

Comment: Error TypeError: Cannot set property msg of undefined at timer

Comment: try to initilize `msg` with empty array like this on top `msg : any[] = []`

Comment: Kindly try to reproduce the same error on stackblitz if possible

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error cannot set property msg of undefined this means 'this' keyword is undefined inside your function block. the this keyword is not getting binded inside your function block

try console.log this first inside your function and check if it is undefined and if it is then try using es6 arrow function syntax or a simple hack is:

```
timer() {
  this.msg = [];
  console.log(this) // if you get empty msg array then bind your this else bind it before the timer function starts(just above the timer())

  let $this = this // use $this every where inside this block and it wont give you undefined error

  if (count < messages.length) {
      $this.msg.push(messages[count])
      console.log(messages[count],count)
      count += 1
  } else {
      clearInterval(interval)
  }

}
```